# Pass smarty template to codeigniter variable and return as JSON data

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, smarty

I was wondering if anyone of you tried to pass a SMARTY template (view) into a variable and later on pass that variable to a json response?. Here is my sample code

```
$content = $this->smarty->view('myview/page', array('var' => 'some value'), true);
echo json_encode(array('success' => true, 'message' => $content));exit;
```

So I was thinking of passing the `$content` variable to a json response. The content is the view/template itself. In simple codeigniter view this is something like this

```
$content = $this->load->view('myview/page', array('var' => 'some value'), true);
echo json_encode(array('success' => true, 'message' => $content));exit;
```

Is this possible in smarty? its just like pass the template/view into a variable? The problem is when i use the `$this->smarty->view('myview/page', array('var' => 'some value'), true)` it automatically renders the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found an answer. Hope this help someone in the future. What I did was to use fetch instead of view.

```
$content = $this->smarty->fetch("myview/page.tpl", array('var' => 'some value'));
echo json_encode(array('success' => true, 'message' => $content));exit;
```